# What is difference Indonesian babel with Bahasa babel ?

Tags: babel

I'm reading Babel manual page 18 and there are bahasa, indonesian, indon,  and bahasai babel. 
I want ask " **What is difference it?**".  I am from Indonesia and I confused use it for hyphenation better. Is Indonesian babel better than others? Or Not, Can you explain it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is none. As you talk Bahasa Indonesia, you should load `\usepackage[bahasai]{babel}`, which is a direct (non-synonym) link to the `bahasa.dtx` [file](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/bahasa).

---

From the [manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) page 18:

> In the following table most of the languages supported by babel are
>   listed, together with the names of the options which you can load
>   babel with for each language.

This means that "**Bahasa** bahasa, indonesian, indon, bahasai, bahasam, malay, meyalu" are all synonyms. You should load one of these in your document, when you use any of these languages (can't tell, if those languages are different as I don't speak any of them). They will support you with hyphenation and all other features which will most certainly be described in the documentation.

---

In order to proof this I had a look in the source:

```
\DeclareOption{bahasa}{\bbl@load@language{bahasai}}
\DeclareOption{bahasai}{\bbl@load@language{bahasai}}
\DeclareOption{bahasam}{\bbl@load@language{bahasam}}
\DeclareOption{indon}{\bbl@load@language{bahasai}}
\DeclareOption{indonesian}{\bbl@load@language{bahasai}}
\DeclareOption{malay}{\bbl@load@language{bahasam}}
\DeclareOption{meyalu}{\bbl@load@language{bahasam}}
```

So there seam to be two non-synonym options `bahasai` and `bahasam`. I am not able to translate this, but maybe those names make it clear to you.

Comment: Why they have different name ? Indonesian , bahasa, indon, and bahasai are one. I only suggest babel for Indonesia is indonesian babel.

Comment: @Hirwanto I do not know that languages so maybe I am wrong: I guess, these are synonyms in the real world, too. Or they are different languages with the same hyphenation rules. Most certainly, it is a matter of taste or of compatibility. Like this, you can collect various old language packages into one or you might split something off later if you want to maintain some very specialized part of this language-family.

Comment: I am from Indonesia , and I have national language is Bahasa Indonesia, I don't know Why  Indonesia babel have different name such bahasa, bahasai, indon, and indonesia

Comment: @Hirwanto They are just synonyms. When you talk "Bahasa Indonesia", I think its good to be able to load `[bahasa]` OR `[indonsian]`. One error less to make for beginners. `[indon]` could be an abbreviation which comes from some older package. There might be old documents having this loaded... why block the compatibility. And maybe Malaysian people do not like to use "indonesian" even if it is the same. I am really guessing around here. The only interesting thing here is: Is there a differnece between `bahasai` and `bahasam`? Can you translate that?

Comment: AFAIK, documentation about Indonesian babel is very little. What is you know where I can found documentation it ?

Comment: bahasai is babel for Indonesia and bahasam is babel for Malaysia

Comment: @Hirwanto Ok, that makes it clear. There are two languages: "Bahasa Indonesia" and "Bahasa Malaysia". Both have their language set (documentation [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-bahasa)) and several synonyms in order to call them.

Comment: I feel this come from some older package like you say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20428/discussion-between-hirwanto-and-larifari).